# Azure Storage custom audit and logs

Tags: azure, logging, azure-diagnostics

I'm writing a small app that reads and writes from Azure Blob Storage (Images, documents, etc.) 
I need to implement some logging that will log activities such as:

1. file uploaded
2. File deleted
3. File updates
   etc.

So, basically I need my log to look something like this:

1. User John Doe Create a container "containerName" on 2016-05-05
2. User Mike Smith removed a blob test.jpg
   etc...

UserIds and other additional info will be sent through method.
Example:  `CreateImage(String CreatedBy)`

Question:
What is the best way to store and create such type of logs? The easiest one is to have SQL database with table Audit and all necessary columns. But I know that Azure has Azure Diagnostics. Can that be used to store and query logs? For example, I will need to see all file manipulations by user, by date, etc.

Comment: Would you be needing the functionality to retrieve this data? If the answer is yes, would you be needing to perform filter on different criteria (like on user, operation performed etc.)?

Comment: @GauravMantri, Hi Guarav. Yes and yes. I will need to see what files were created by a specific user, etc

Answer (score 0):

I would go using one of these ways:

1) **Azure Storage Tables** for logs. Here, you may store everything you need regarding logs. Then, if you need a functionality to get/filter/etc, you may look  into [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894039.aspx) to Azure Tables or even [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/richclient/datacontextdrivers.aspx) if you need the desktop-ready software. However, some design considerations should be taken into account - design guidance is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/).

2) **Application Insights**. Using [custom events functionality](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/), you may go with the powerful logging and then, on the portal, see how it is going. You may attach some metadata to the custom event, and then aggregate/filter/see that using convenient web interface. Or connect log4net to the AI, if you want to stream logs to the AI. AI may export its logs into the Azure Storage continuously, so you may take that and dive into it later.

IMHO, i would not say that SQL Database is the appropriate store for logs - it looks like too much (in terms of resources, maybe price, etc) for me for storing the logs in the full-fledged DB. Not very relevant, but interesting reading about working with a [lot of records](https://www.troyhunt.com/working-with-154-million-records-on/).